# Python: Why is pygame.event.key.get_pressed() not working?

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to make it where if i press space when the program has already been launched it will play my song.
It opens up, then i get the loading animation on my cursor(when cursor is over the program.).The programs crashed.

```
`import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
bf = 'bg.jpg'
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
background = pygame.image.load(bf) .convert()
screen.blit(background, (0,0))
pygame.display.update()
pygame.display.set_caption('Letters')
keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()


while True:
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        pygame.mixer.music.load('ht.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1, start=0)


running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:

            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Please explain it me like I was a kid.(I am new in pygame.)

Answer (score 1):

Your program is stuck here:

```
while True:
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        pygame.mixer.music.load('ht.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1, start=0)
```

The loop never ends. Once you obtain the condition you needed, you should break the loop:

```
while True:
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        pygame.mixer.music.load('ht.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1, start=0)
        break
```

Or just remove the `while` loop altogether, you don't seem to need it:

```
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    pygame.mixer.music.load('ht.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1, start=0)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

You don't receive events because of pygame doesn't started. If you remove your `while True` loop then pygame will start and begin to receive events